# NoMethodError(you have a nil object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

My code is

```
def attachmentupload
    options = {}
    options['ext'] = params['upload']['file'].original_filename.split('.').last
    options['content_type'] = params['upload']['file'].content_type
    options['file'] = params['upload']['file']
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads',
    options['file'].original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(options['file'].read)
```

I am getting a `NoMethodError(you have a nil object)` error in line `options['ext'] = params['upload']['file'].original_filename.split('.').last`.

Please help me out

Comment: To format your code in StackOverflow, place at least 4 spaces ahead of each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have no 'upload' parameter, or you have one, but it does not contain a 'file' parameter.

Maybe this happened because you did not pass the `multipart: true` option to the form helper in your view?

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files